# Why does my code work correctly when I run wg.Wait() inside a goroutine?

Tags: asynchronous, go, goroutine

I have a list of urls that I am scraping. What I want to do is store all of the successfully scraped page data into a channel, and when I am done, dump it into a slice. I don't know how many successful fetches I will get, so I cannot specify a fixed length. I expected the code to reach `wg.Wait()` and then wait until all the `wg.Done()` methods are called, but I never reached the `close(queue)` statement. Looking for a similar answer, I came across this SO answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31573574/5721702

where the author does something similar:

```
ports := make(chan string)
toScan := make(chan int)
var wg sync.WaitGroup

// make 100 workers for dialing
for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for p := range toScan {
            ports <- worker(*host, p)
        }
    }()
}

// close our receiving ports channel once all workers are done
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(ports)
}()
```

As soon as I wrapped my `wg.Wait()` inside the goroutine, `close(queue)` was reached:

```
urls := getListOfURLS()
activities := make([]Activity, 0, limit)
queue := make(chan Activity)
for i, activityURL := range urls {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(i int, url string) {
        defer wg.Done()
        activity, err := extractDetail(url)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        queue <- activity
    }(i, activityURL)
}
    // calling it like this without the goroutine causes the execution to hang
// wg.Wait() 
// close(queue)

    // calling it like this successfully waits
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(queue)
}()
for a := range queue {
    // block channel until valid url is added to queue
    // once all are added, close it
    activities = append(activities, a)
}
```

Why does the code not reach the `close` if I don't use a goroutine for `wg.Wait()`? I would think that the all of the `defer wg.Done()` statements are called so eventually it would clear up, because it gets to the `wg.Wait()`. Does it have to do with receiving values in my channel?

Comment: Could you show the whole code?

Comment: By default channels are unbuffered, meaning that they will only accept sends if there is a corresponding receive ready to receive the sent value.So when you are sending activity to queue, there is no corresponding receive for that and it is blocked.All goroutines are blocked and finally wg.wait will hang. There is concept called buffered channel which can be used to buffer more than one input.Go through https://gobyexample.com/channel-buffering

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to wait for goroutines to finish in a separate thread because `queue` needs to be read from. When you do the following:

```
queue := make(chan Activity)
for i, activityURL := range urls {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(i int, url string) {
        defer wg.Done()
        activity, err := extractDetail(url)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        queue <- activity // nothing is reading data from queue.
    }(i, activityURL)
}

wg.Wait() 
close(queue)

for a := range queue {
    activities = append(activities, a)
}
```

Each goroutine blocks at `queue <- activity` since `queue` is unbuffered and nothing is reading data from it. This is because the range loop on `queue` is in the main thread after `wg.Wait`.

`wg.Wait` will only unblock once all the goroutine return. But as mentioned, all the goroutines are blocked at channel send.

When you use a separate goroutine to wait, code execution actually reaches the range loop on `queue`.

```
// wg.Wait does not block the main thread.
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(queue)
}()
```

This results in the goroutines unblocking at the `queue <- activity` statement (main thread starts reading off `queue`) and running until completion. Which in turn calls each individual `wg.Done`.

Once the waiting goroutine get past `wg.Wait`, `queue` is closed and the main thread exits the range loop on it.

Comment: Given that your explanation makes a lot of sense but only after reading it, that makes me wonder, is the way I wrote it the best way to write it? I did not intend my logic to work out that way, so I'm worried that the code is a little convoluted and not too readable.

Comment: This is pretty much how problems like this are handled. Some people prefer to rely exclusively on channels but there's nothing wrong with wait groups. As for readability, the issue might be with understanding the flow of code. And that is something you'll get comfortable with as you work with the language more.

Answer (score 2):

`queue` channel is unbuffered so every goroutine trying to write to it gets blocked because reader process is not yet started. So no goroutinte can write and they all hang - as a result `wg.Wait` waits forever.
Try to launch reader in a separate goroutine:

```
go func() {
    for a := range queue {
        // block channel until valid url is added to queue
        // once all are added, close it
       activities = append(activities, a)
    }
}()
```

and then start waiter:

```
wg.Wait() 
close(queue)
```

This way you can not to accumulate all the data in channel and overload it, but get data as it comes and put to target slice.

Comment: You mean calling the reader first in a goroutine then calling the waiter without the goroutine? I tried this and it returned 3 results inside my slice instead of the expected 4. I suspect it has to do with closing the queue a little bit too early after all the `wg.Done()` were reached and the slice was returned before the last item could be appended.

Comment: Yes. In this case you need to need to wait until reader finishes otherwise last record could be lost.